# Angular can't set httpHeader

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, http-headers

Hi people i need help on this project i can't find a solution,
i'm trying to do a post http request on my server node JS but i must set the content type as charset UTF-8 or i can't read the post data on my server
I'm using Angular 6 and this is my code,
in this way i got no payload data on the server because not set the utf-8 on the request-headers

```
      let headers= new HttpHeaders()
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    const options={headers};
    this.http
        .post('http://localhost:3000/user/signIn', JSON.stringify(form.value), options )
        .subscribe(
            res=>console.log(res),
            err=>console.log(err)
        )
}
```

in this other way i got an error on the console

```
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    });
    const options={headers};
    this.http
        .post('http://localhost:3000/user/signIn', JSON.stringify(form.value), options )
        .subscribe(
            res=>console.log(res),
            err=>console.log(err)
        )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc9Mx.png)

the error says i'm not set allow origin on the server but in the call i set the header allow origin like this

```
routes.route('/signIn')
.post((req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    signInController.signIn(req.body)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(`*** return fullfiled promise =)`);
            res.status(response.code).send(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(`*** return rejected promise =(`);
            res.status(error.code).send(error.data);
        })
})
```

Please can someone help me on how to set the httpHeaders in charset UTF-8 i'm stucked.

Comment: do you use expressjs in serverside?

Comment: You need to add headers to  Access-Control-Allow-Headers on your server code

Comment: const options={headers:headers};, and NOT use JSON.stringify(form.value), just form.value, see https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

Comment: thanks i solved by adding to nodejs the header on server Access-Control-Allow-Headers and on response of server Access-Control-Allow-Headers and on cvlient matching the solution of ELISEO const options={headers:headers};, and NOT use JSON.stringify(form.value), thanks guys you're the best